# SEO preparation for upcoming new site

Tags: seo, content, ranking, website-design, web-crawlers

I booked a domain and I created an image saying that the site is soon to be launched.

What SEO preparations should I make to avoid harming my SEO ranking? Because my page is blank, the image itself is displayed with CSS. Only the title is filled with information. There is no description nor keywords. Will it hurt my SEO ranking if Google or some other crawler would wander to my site?

Comment: Its all about hand written unique content, relevant and quality backlinks and social presence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is nothing to worry about. Crawlers come back regularly and will eventually index your new content once it is there. Domains can even be parked for years that way.